# how to change Jasper report background color when exporting to html?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

how to change background color in jasper report when exporting to html, but the colors appears when exporting to PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRHtmlExporterParameter.html#IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND

```
IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND

public static final JRHtmlExporterParameter IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND

A boolean value specifying whether the report background should be white. If this parameter is   not set, the default background will appear, depending on the selected CSS styles.

PROPERTY_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND

public static final java.lang.String PROPERTY_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND

Property whose value is used as default state of the IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND export flag.

This property is set by default (true).

See Also:
    JRProperties, Constant Field Values
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, now the default color is appears, can i change that to the color that i want?